# How to load different games through a main menu (Java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, menu

I am new to making a simple, offline Java game which consists of a few mini games with basic GUI (Swing). How does one go about loading different mini games through a main menu? For example, if I was making a website, I can put hyperlinks on the main page to link to different pages. Would one clear the screen first and then load the class which contains the game and its graphical contents?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These can be achieved by the following steps, you need to code yourself !

1. You can keep your `different games in different classes` and these classes would have a particular call methods  which must be returning a `PANEL/Jpanel` with the game in it !
2. Now in your main method, there must be a `Main Panel` which would have different `buttons/links` to load different games and a `space` to load the game on the main panel.
3. The `action of these buttons` would `call the respective methods of the game` and `load the panel return by the method in the space` !

Thats the simplest explanation !

Comment: Thank you for the ideas, especially on step 1 through returning a PANEL/JPanel.